# override default obstacle avoidance in turtlebot navigation

Tags: navigation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have built an obstacle avoidance algorithm based on 3D optical flow via PointCloud on a TurtleBot platform. I would like to test it with the navigation stack but the obstacle avoidance is already implemented by default.
I would like the robot to ignore the obstacles that are not on the map.
Can I remove the automatic obstacle avoidance or deactivate it to plug in my node (or code) ?
That would be of great help, since I don't have much time to write by myself whole global and local planners.
If I set the static_map parameter of local_costmap_params.yaml to true, will it do the trick ?
Thank you for your suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36011/override-default-obstacle-avoidance-in-turtlebot-navigation/) by [Yannis](https://answers.ros.org/users/2569/yannis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2012-06-07

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-06-07**:
3D optical flow is interesting... could you make the code available for people to use.

**Comment by [Yannis](https://answers.ros.org/users/2569/yannis/) on 2012-06-07**:
I cannot release my code for now, it's still in development, but I will as soon as I finish my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To "remove" the automatic obstacle avoidance on the amcl navigation, I modified a setting : obstacle_range in turtlebot_navigation package, in costmap_common_params.yaml. So I put it to 0.05, like that no obstacle will be detected unless it's almost touching the robot.

---

Originally posted by [Yannis](https://answers.ros.org/users/2569/yannis/) with karma: 88 on 2012-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0